# Database Table Design / Setup

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm trying to setup a PostgreSQL database for a calendar app, and was wondering what would be the preferred way to set up one of the tables.

If I want to have to have multiple users, would the best way to setup the table be:

UserID | Start Time | End Time | Activity |

Or would it be better to do:

User ID | Activity | 8am | 8:30am | 9am | ...| 12am | ... | 7:30am |

The time granularity could be 15 min or 5 min too if that would be the better choice.

The first way would likely be cleaner, but ideally I don't want to let things overlap, but the second way may be more difficult to work with?

Comment: The first choice is better. But perhaps you should implement the second choice, in order to learn why it's a bad design. So...if you really are trying to produce a working app, go with #1. If you want to learn a negative lesson, go with #2. Best of luck.

Comment: *"ideally I don't want to let things overlap . . ."* To do this the first way, you'll probably want to implement StartTime, EndTime as a [range data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html), and use an exclusion constraint (same link) to guarantee there's no overlapping. You'll probably want the btree_gist extension (same link), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st example is better. But, minimum of 3 tables.

1. User - you define it.
2. Timetable: RowID | UserID | Start Time (datetime) | End Time (datetime) | ActivityID
3. Activity - you define what activity details go in.